# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'. MVC using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC application uses a stored procedure that returns an object like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<SP_DatabaseFirst_Result> SP_DatabaseFirst()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<SP_DatabaseFirst_Result>("SP_DatabaseFirst");
}
```

And I have a document repository class and that is filtering the results of the stored procedures output:

```
public IEnumerable<SP_DatabaseFirst_Result> GetAllOfficeStaff() 
{
    return  DocumentDb.SP_DatabaseFirst().Select(s => s).OrderBy(s => s.sName);
}
```

Finally I am trying to return ViewData from my controller as an `ActionResult`:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

        return ViewData["MyData"]= DocumentDd.GetAllOfficeStaff();
}
```

However, I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: you should return a view. If you want the access the data on the view, you can send it as model of the view. Eg: return View(DocumentDd.GetAllOfficeStaff());

Comment: Refer the inheritance hierarchy for [ActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) for what you can return (you cannot return `ViewData`)

Comment: I think what you want is pass the data to view. If so use, return View(DocumentDd.GetAllOfficeStaff());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
 return View(DocumentDd.GetAllOfficeStaff());
```

Instead of

```
return ViewData["MyData"]= DocumentDd.GetAllOfficeStaff();
```

Solved the problem, Many Thanks to #fredho